# Give S3 Full access cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I have two amazon accounts Account-A and Account-B. I want to give Account-B full control to all S3 related operations in Account-A for example Account-B can create/delete/list buckets belonging to Account-A.

Can you point me to how it's done? So far I was only able to find how to grant cross account access to a single S3 bucket but not to all S3 functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [AWS doc walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html#access-policies-walkthrough-cross-account-permissions-acctA-tasks), then set the bucket policy as (my changes from the doc have `//` comments):

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example permissions",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:*", // ALL S3 actions
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "*" // ALL resources with an 's3:' operation
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to assign cross-account permissions for Amazon S3:

#### Using Bucket Policies

- Add a Bucket Policy *to each desired bucket* that grants permission to the other account
- Add permissions to the desired IAM Users and IAM Roles in Account-B that allow them to access the buckets in Account-A

Note that the permissions are **required in both directions**.

The downside to this method is that the Bucket Policy must be applied to *every* bucket that you want to make available. Also, this **will not work for creating new buckets** since there is no bucket policy to grant access.

#### Using an IAM Role

- Create an IAM Role in Account-A (`Role-A`) that has all desired S3 permissions, and a Trust Policies that trusts Account-B
- From Account-B, call `AssumeRole()` on `Role-A`
- Use the returned credentials to manage S3 resources in Account-A

This does not require any Bucket Policies, but has the requirement to call `AssumeRole()`.

See also: [Provide cross-account access to objects in S3 buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)